# Heroku PHP - file_get_contents from Heroku Server to itself causes H12 Request Timeout

Tags: php, heroku, load-balancing, file-get-contents, http-status-code-503

When I make an HTTP-request in my PHP code running on Heroku to the server itself, I often get a Request Timeout (H12), although the request page itself runs smoothly when I open it in the browser. I assume this has something to do with load balancing or the inability of one server to handle two concurrent requests?

Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Pseudo-code running on myapp.herokuapp.com/site1.php

```
file_get_contents("myapp.herokuapp.com/site2.php");
```

Pseudo-code running on myapp.herokuapp.com/site2.php

```
echo "Hello";
```

Result in the logs:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=site2.php host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.2 connect=3ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using cURL option instead of file_get_contents

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "myapp.herokuapp.com/site2.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$temp = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```